# Unity3D: Change Background Image on a GUI Skin

Tags: unity

So I'm testing with GUI Skins and trying to make something cool, and I want to change the background image of the application background. This is what I mean
[image]

In the screenshot above, the background is just blue, i'd like to change that to an image so it looks a lot better. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the new GUI system?

If so remember that this is within your scene view or is actually in the 3D rendering view.
This means that whatever you put behind the canvas object (Z-Transform) is going to be rendered as the background (even 3D Objects).

You could easily also just pick a plane and rotate it 90 degrees to show a simple background with a texture/material.

If you want to learn more about how to utilise the menu system and its capabilities I would recommend you look into these tutorials by [3DBuzz](http://www.3dbuzz.com/training/view/modern-ui-dev-in-unity-46/introduction-modern-gui)